# Virial theorem for a binary system

Tags: orbital-mechanics, binary-star, celestial-mechanics

I am trying to derive the virial theorem but for two stars orbiting each other. I know the derivation for the general virial theorem with i particles but I am wondering if there is a quicker or more elegant derivation when it comes to proving the virial theorem with only two masses (I am not assuming that the two bodies are in circular orbits around each other).

Comment: Do you consider the teo srars as two particles?

Comment: Reducing the mass turns it into a one particle case, but integrating averages of KE and PE across the orbit equation seems to produce a lot of ugh algebra - some other approach is definitely needed.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Yes, I am assuming the two stars are particles.